# How to stop django from inserting column into MySQL if record already exists

Tags: python, html, mysql, django

Models.py:

```py
class signUpUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    passwd = models.TextField()
    passwd2 = models.TextField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique = True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.passwd = make_password(self.passwd)
            self.passwd2 = make_password(self.passwd2)
        super(signUpUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)               

    class Meta:
        db_table = "users"
```

views.py

```py
def signUp(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('username') and request.POST.get('passwd') and request.POST.get('email'):
            post = signUpUser()
            post.username = request.POST.get('username')
            post.passwd = request.POST.get('passwd')
            post.passwd2 = request.POST.get('passwd2')
            post.email = request.POST.get('email')
            post.save()
            messages.success(request, "Success.")
    return render(request, "signup.html")
```

signup.html

```html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/css/styles.css' %}">
    <body style="background-color: rgb(37, 37, 37);">
    <script src="{% static 'js/index.js' %}"></script>
    <title>Document</title>

    <body class="bkg_signup">

        <div id="particles-js">
    
    <div class="top-nav">
        <a href="{% url 'hpage' %}">HOME</a>
        <a href="{% url 'prodpage' %}">PRODUCTS</a>
        <a href="{% url 'cpage' %}">CONTACT</a>
        <a href="{% url 'apage' %}">ABOUT</a>
        <a style="float: right;" href="{% url 'lpage' %}">LOGIN</a>
        <a style="float: right;" href="{% url 'spage' %}">SIGN UP</a>
        </div>
    
        <div class="item-box2">
            <div class="div-align2" style="font-size: 28px;">
                <h1 style="margin-right: 40px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">Sign Up</h1>
            </div>
        
            <form class="fontmaker" method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input style="border-color: black;" class="input-corners" placeholder="Username" type="text" id="username" name="username" required><br>
                <input style="border-color: black;" class="input-corners2" placeholder="Password" type="text" id="passwd" name="passwd" minlength="5" required><br>
                <input style="border-color: black;" class="input-corners2" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="text" id="passwd2" name="passwd2" minlength="5" required><br>
                <input style="border-color: black;" class="input-corners" placeholder="Email" type="text" id="email" name="email" required><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" class="rounded-corners8" id="signUpBtn">
                
                
            </form>
        </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

const password = document.getElementById("passwd");
const confirm_password = document.getElementById("passwd2");
const username = document.getElementById("username");

document.addEventListener('change', () => {
    function validatePassword() {
        if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
        } else if(password.value == username.value) {
            password.setCustomValidity("Password cannot be the same as username.");
        } else {
            confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
        };
            
  };

  password.onchange = validatePassword;
  confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;

});


</script>


</head>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/particles.js@2.0.0/demo/js/app.js"></script>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried looking around on other SO questions and the django docs, looks like even though I have unique set to True it still updates to the mysql database with the same username. How can I stop it from updating to the database again and showing a error message in html to tell the end user that they need to pick a different username.

Comment: Use a *`ModelForm`*...

Comment: @IainShelvington: I think it is not the db itself, it simply aims to insert a new record in the db, because there is no form that rejects this.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ah you're right, I misunderstood "stop Django inserting" to mean it was doing so successfully

Comment: I see, is there any method in django that would could read from the db and prevent it from happening? Or do I need to implement this myself.